# Will Web Server Log WGet Requests?

Tags: logging, web, request, wget

I am new to running servers, but will Wget requests be logged in a web server? What kind of requests will be logged, for example, in Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the server's point of view wget request is not different than any other HTTP request. If apache is configured to log HTTP requests it would log all of them, including wget. If it's configured to log user-agent field you should see which particular requests were from wget in the log file.